# Concatenate String in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I've been trying to concatenate a string in MASM and am having some difficulty. First of all, my output at this point is a 0 with a tree-like character, but I think that perhaps my `WriteString` (from the Irvine library) is not being used properly. Does `WriteString` write from `edx` or `eax`?
I also know that when using strings, I need to work with pointers to the addresses of their first character rather than the entire string; this is what I am trying to do with the buffer and the OFFSET pointers, but I am not sure that this is entirely correct. I am also unsure if the push and pop is necessary, and if it is, what exactly it does. 
Please help! Thanks very much in advance.

Here is the coding that I've written:

```
TITLE Str_Concat        (WA5.asm)

; Program Description: This program concatenates a source string to a target string.
; Author: 
; Date Created: 2/6/2013


INCLUDE C:\IrvineExamplesVS2010a\Irvine32.inc

.data
    source BYTE "Rocks",0
    target BYTE "Zachary",0
    buffer BYTE 24 DUP (0)

.code
main PROC
    push ds    
    pop es

    mov esi, OFFSET source
    mov edi, OFFSET target
    cld                         ;direction = forward
    mov cx, LENGTHOF source
    rep movsb

    call WriteString
    call crlf


        exit        ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

Irvine explains most of his procedures in his book.  The source for his Library is also available for download from his site.  In the source, he left some info on what the procs take as parameters, in what registers, and what each of his procs returns.  Here is the description from `WriteString`:

```
WriteString PROC
;
; Writes a null-terminated string to standard
; output. Input parameter: EDX points to the
; string.
; Last update: 9/7/01
;--------------------------------------------------------
```

So, after reading that, in what register would you put the address of `target`?  You cannot use `edi` "as is" since the original address in `edi` has been incremented by `rep movsb`

On a side note, you are *not* concatenating the strings, but overwriting the string in `target` with the string in `source`.  You defined `buffer`, but never use it.  `buffer` is to hold both strings together?  If so, you need to copy `target` into `buffer` then copy `source` into `buffer`.